# Using an electric/magnetic field to cool particles

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, atomic-physics, cooling, cold-atoms

I was just thinking that temperature and the motion of atoms are connected. Hence, I was wondering why we can’t just use a magnetic or electric field to hold atoms more or less in place, lowering their motion and presumably lowering their temperature (I suppose in a similar manner to using laser cooling to slow an atoms momentum but instead using a field). Would that work? Thanks!

Comment: Like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_refrigeration ?

Answer (score 0):

You've probably heard the term [*laser cooling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_cooling). And a laser beam is a propagating wave in the electromagnetic field, so I'll claim this meets the criteria you asked about "Using an electric/magnetic field to cool particles".

Very roughly, the way laser cooling works is, if you have a gas, the particles in the gas will be moving randomly in all directions. If you tune a laser so that it interacts more with the particles moving in one direction and not the other, then when an atom scatters a photon from the laser, it will slow down (losing energy), with the energy causing a state transition within the atom. Later, the atom will spontaneously release the energy from being in the excited state, but since this process is random it is equally likely to cause an increase or a decrease in kinetic energy. Over many such interactions, on average the atoms lose energy, and the gas is cooled.

Comment: I’m familiar with laser cooling, I was just wondering if introducing a repelling field all around a particle capable of reacting to it cause it to stop moving around as much, thus reducing it’s temperature? What are your thoughts?

Comment: @dl19, how would you arrange that a static field always acts to slow the particles?

Comment: I was thinking possibly having the particle of interest being charged either positive or negative and having surrounding charges of the same polarity, thus causing a repelling force. @The Photon

Comment: But once the particle is stationary, the repelling force will continue to accelerate it, increasing its kinetic energy.

Comment: I suppose my thought process was to position all the surrounding electric charges at a position such that there will be a natural equilibrium point for the particle to maneuver to and rest at a particular point.

Comment: @dl19 1) there's [no stable equilibrium in an electrostatic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem)
2) even if there was, how would you actually extract the energy? A static field is conservative, there is no dissipation